# If-block not entered, not sure why

Tags: c++, file, fstream

This function is supposed to read each line of a file and compare it to a user-input string and check if they match. It basically prevents duplicate information in the file. Anyway, the program doesn't go into my "if (loginsFile.is_open())" statement and I don't understand why.

```
fstream loginsFile;
loginsFile.open("C:/logins.txt", ios::in | ios::out | ios::trunc | ios :: app | ios:: ate);

string username;
string password;
string info;
bool exists = true;
CheckingAccount cA;
SavingsAccount sA;

do {
    cout << "Enter Username: ";
    cin >> username;
    cout << "Enter Password: ";
    cin >> password;
    cout << endl;
    info = username + " " + password;
    if (loginsFile.is_open()){
        while (loginsFile.good()){
            string line;
            getline(loginsFile, line);
            cout << "line is " << line.substr(line.find_last_of(" ")) << "\n" << "info is " << line.substr(line.find_last_of(" "));
            if (line.substr(line.find_last_of(" ")) == info.substr(0, info.find_last_of(" "))){
                exists = false;
                cout << "Username already exists!" << endl << "Program is not case sensitive!";
            } //end if
        } //end while
    } //end if
} while (exists == true); //end do while

loginsFile << info << endl;
loginsFile.close();
logins[info] = make_pair(cA, sA);
cout << info.substr(0, info.find(' ')) << " Has Been Successfully Registered!" << "\n" << "\n";
return logins;
```

Comment: are you using window7? Windows 7 does not allow read/write from `C:`, try to put it into `c:\\temp\\lognis.txt`

Comment: the path is really a folder in my desktop. I just cut it down wen i posted the question. Im not using windows 7. im using windows xp prof

Comment: You open the file with `ios::trunc`... doesn't that remove all the lines?  If so, how can you expect to read from it?  If not, perhaps you don't have write permission to the file?

Comment: Good point, Tony. Chuck, are you certain it's *not* entering the if, rather than not entering the while...though that would result in an infinite outer loop...but I guess that's happening anyway?

Comment: Do you already have the file open elsewhere in the program? http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/ "If the stream is already associated with a file (i.e., it is already open), calling this function fails."

Comment: To test the fail bit: `(loginsFile.rdstate() & ios::failbit) != 0`.

Answer (score 2):

Your if-statement isn't being entered because the file isn't open. The file isn't opening because you cannot combine "std::ios::trunc" (truncate file removing all contents) and "std::ios::app" (append to end of file) because they contradict each other.

Answer (score 0):

Check failbit after you call open(). If it's set, then the open op failed. Is the forward slash in your path causing a problem, perhaps?

Comment: No the path is fine. I use the same path in other parts of the program and it works fine. The problem is with the if block i think

Comment: i dont know what a failbit. Is that a c++ thing? lol im a java person who just started learning c++ forgive me, i dont know all the fancy terminology

Comment: You can also check the return value of fail() for your fstream, which checks both failbit and badbit: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/fail/

Comment: As a Java programmer, you've probably come to expect things like calling "open" to throw an exception if they fail. You'll need to check those expectations if you work much in C++. "assert" will become your friend.

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/open/
In section mode, it says:
If the mode has both trunc and app set, the opening operation fails. It also fails if either is set but out is not, or if both app and in are set.